# Not able to connect to dataverse in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dataverse

Getting below error while connecting to dataverse in power BI. Having all the access needed.

DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

Tried to connect with org.creds but not able to connect to the tables because of the above error